# Convert Eth Key to Geth Key

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum, keystore

I have some eth keys that I would like to convert to geth keys. There was a previous post about this, however the solution provided was to use ethkey, but this tool has now been deprecated. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool was deprecated [because](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/issues/3113):

> We retired the `ethkey` command and files are now compatible, no need to
>   stick to a certain file naming scheme. I think we are fine here. Key
>   management is not something we highly support, it should be moved out
>   of the node's domain anyway.

So it *should* just work. (If it doesn't, then it might be worth commenting on the relevant GitHub issues page in the above link.)